# Use an object to select columns in dplyr

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I'm trying to find the row wise max of columns selected using a vector of column names. However, dplyr doesn't seem to accept a vector of names which each have "" around them.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
ladder.channel <- c("channel_4")
bleed.channels <- c("channel_1", "channel_2", "channel_3", "channel_5")
  
  y <- x %>%
    mutate(correction = -pmax(bleed.channels)) %>%
    mutate(channel.corr = ladder.channel + correction)
```

But I get this error:

```
    Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `correction`.
ℹ `correction = -pmax(bleed.channels)`.
x invalid argument to unary operator
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 8. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 9. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
```

Any idea how to get dplyr to accept a vector to select column names. I've read a few posts, including using `all_of`, but can't get it working ([How to call column names from an object in dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114415/how-to-call-column-names-from-an-object-in-dplyr), [Use dynamic variable names in `dplyr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr))

Comment: You can use `... %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(max_val = max(across(all_of(bleed.channels))))` or `... %>% mutate(correction = pmax(!!!syms(bleed.channels)))`.

Comment: It looks like your error is generated by the `-pmax(bleed.channels)` bit, so it doesn't seem to be a `dplyr` issue.

Comment: Great thanks @27-ϕ-9, both of these work, though I'm not sure what !!!syms is doing. I've now got a problem with the second line though, as if I use !!!syms with `ladder.channel`, it won't let me specify the `correction` column!

Comment: I don't think that this issue should have been closed. `library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(
  channel_1 = c(1,2,3),
  channel_2 = c(4,5,6),
  channel_3 = c(7,8,9)
)

ladder.channel <- c("channel_1")
bleed.channels <- c("channel_2", "channel_3")

x %>% mutate(
  correction = -pmax(!!!syms(ladder.channel))
) %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(channel.corr =  sum(correction, !!!syms(bleed.channels)))

`. I can now not format it correctly. However, you need to then perform `rowwise()` and again use `!!!syms()`.

Comment: You can do  `... %>% mutate(correction = -pmax(!!!syms(vars)), channel.corr = !!sym(ladder.channel) + correction) `.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've now got the channel.corr mutation working with `rowwise() %>%
    mutate(channel.corr = sum(across(all_of(c(ladder.channel, "correction")))))`. However, it's so slow! Is there a way that's gets around the calculation burden of `rowwise()`?